# I have an old Windows NT Workstation with AutoLogon. How can I disable this to login as an Admin?

Tags: login, windows

I have an running Windows NT (in a virtual box) that runs some legacy services.
It logins automatically with user and password (for availability reasons).
Now i need to do some administration, and the connected user has no piviliges.
Logging off automatically logs me on again.

how can i solve this?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On XP, holding the Shift key on boot will prevent the autologon which would need to be done from the VM console. I don't have an NT machine to test this on though.

Answer (score 2):

Using your own machine (or any other) connect remotely to the machine using "net use" and an authorized account. Then run regedit, connect to the remote machine, and edit the registry key responsible for the AutoLogon.